# Can we have dynamic headers in spreadjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, spreadjs

I have integrated `spreadJS` with react framework. In `spreadjs` they only use the header name specified in JSON and accordingly the data get displayed in the spreadsheet.

Can we have dynamic headers and their respective value using JSON?

```
import { SpreadSheets, Worksheet, Column } from '@grapecity/spread-sheets-react';

this.data = [
    {
        "id": 1934,
        "date": "2018-11-01",
        "value": 10.0
    },
    {
        "id": 1935,
        "date": "2018-12-01",
        "value": 10.0
    },
    {
        "id": 1935,
        "date": "2018-12-01",
        "value": 10.0
    }
]


class SpreadJsSample extends React.Component {
   render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <SpreadSheets>
          <Worksheet data={this.data}>
            {this.data.map(index => {
              <Column width={150} data={index.date} />;
            })}
          </Worksheet>
        </SpreadSheets>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I am getting following errors

1. The above error occurred in the Worksheet component:
2. Uncaught  Cannot read property 'type' of null

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The function you're passing to .map() isn't returning anything, so your array of columns is currently `[undefined, undefined, undefined`].

You just need to return the `<Column>`:

`{this.data.map(index => {
    return <Column width={150} data={index.date} />;
})}`

or

`{this.data.map(index => <Column width={150} data={index.date} /> )}`